# How to stop firebase notification if app is in foreground

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Is there any way to stop showing the push notification when the app is in foreground ?

Right now we are receiving all the messages either the app is in foreground or in background but I want to display the Firebase push notification only when the app is in foreground or minimise.

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation of the `FirebaseMessagingService` you can implement the `onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage)` method as follows:

```
override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
    if (AppLifecycleManager.isInForeground) {
        //silently discard the received notification
        return
    }
    //continue handling the received notification
    //...
}
```

For implementing the AppLifecycleManager you can use [ProcessLifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner), creating something like this:

```
object AppLifecycleManager : LifecycleObserver {
    var isInForeground = true
    
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun onEnterForeground() {
        isInForeground = true
    }
    
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun onEnterBackground() {
        isInForeground = false
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to register your lifecycle observer in the onCreate of your Application class:

```
...
ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(AppLifecycleManager)
...
```

One more important thing to note is that in order to have full control over the notifications received, data message should be used. Check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) for more info.

Comment: notification automatically shows us when there is new notification.

Comment: are you using FCM? in that case using *data message* intead of *notification message* may help to prevent the system to automatically display the notification once it is received

Answer (score 0):

Showing notification depends on us.We can configure like showing notification only when app is in background and disable when app is in foreground.We can check whether app is in foreground or background like below.

```
private boolean isAppInForeground(Context context) {

    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (runningProcesses == null) {
        return false;
    }
   String packageName = context.getPackageName();
   for (RunningAppProcessInfo runningProcess : runningProcesses) {
   if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && runningProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
       return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

}

If it returns true just don't show notifcation.

Comment: actually we are not showing notification it automatically shows when there is new notification for my device.